# QSettings: guide for switching from registry to ini format?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

On Windows, the [QSettings](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsettings.html#details) can store the application settings in either:

- the registry
- or in an `.ini` file

Currently I'm estimating the cost of changing from registry to `.ini` files for an application.
Some of the code in that application currently retrieves the values of specific registry keys and I'm wondering how that could work with `.ini` files.

My questions are:

1. how to safely switch from registry to `.ini` files
2. and what to do with the code that queries the registry directly by key names?

Comment: 1. `QSettings` may serialize different data formats. But ofter, it makes .ini file not user-friendly. 2. Redesign your application.

Comment: I don't think it will take much effort. Just initialize your QSettings object in the way it save data rather into a file than in native format.

Comment: We use next-to-executable ini files (after porting from registry/global ini file) in our projects. The port is pretty easy. Just write an singleton wrapper object for your QSettings-Ini implementation and call these instead of QSettings directly.